# How many ways can a group of 10 players be formed from 13 national players and 3 junior players such that the group contains exactly 1 junior player?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a group of 10 players be formed from 13 national players and 3 junior players such that the group contains exactly 1 junior player?

My approach:

Out of $10$ players, one needs to be from the junior list. Hence

$\binom{13}{9} + \binom{3}{1} = 715 + 3 = 718$

Is the approach and answer correct?

Comment: No, it is incorrect. You need to ponder a bit as to what might be wrong.

Comment: @trueblueanil I think I need to multiply 715 with 3 and not add it?

Comment: Your thought is right, but you must get clear in your mind when the addition law is to be used, and when the multiplication law is to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are choosing the junior players and national players at the same time, so the terms should be multiplied.